# Usage of state in updateState method (Persistent Actor)

Tags: scala, akka

From *Akka Cookbook*, example from  chapter *Persistent Actors*. In `SamplePersistentActor.scala` there is line of code that I don't quite understand. Here's the full code of 2 files.

**`SamplePersistentActor.scala:`**

```
  class SamplePersistenceActor extends PersistentActor {
  override val persistenceId = "unique-id-1"
  var state = ActiveUsers()
   def updateState(event:Event) = state = state.update(event)

  val receiveRecover: Receive = {
    case evt: Event => updateState(evt)
    case SnapshotOffer(_, snapshot: ActiveUsers) => state = snapshot
  }

 override val receiveCommand: Receive = {
    case UserUpdate(userId, Add) =>
      persist(AddUserEvent(userId))(updateState)
    case UserUpdate(userId, Remove) =>
      persist(RemoveUserEvent(userId))(updateState)
    case "snap" => saveSnapshot(state)
    case "print" => println(state)
  }

}
```

**`SamplePersistentModel.scala:`**

```
sealed trait UserAction
case object Add extends UserAction
case object Remove extends UserAction
case class UserUpdate(userId: String, action: UserAction)

sealed trait Event
case class AddUserEvent(userId: String) extends Event
case class RemoveUserEvent(userId: String) extends Event

case class ActiveUsers(users: Set[String] = Set.empty[String])
{
  def update(evt: Event)= evt match {
    case AddUserEvent(userId) => copy(users + userId)
    case RemoveUserEvent(userId) => copy(users.filterNot(_ == userId))
  }
  override def toString = s"$users"
}
```

**My question**
What is the purpose of `= state` (or `= this.state` if I'm correct) in line `def updateState(event:Event) = state = state.update(event)`. Why can't we just use `def updateState(event:Event) = state.update(event)`?

Found similar in [documentation example](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/v2.5.19/akka-docs/src/test/scala/docs/persistence/PersistentActorExample.scala#L8-L48).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your sample code:

```
def updateState(event: Event) = state = state.update(event)
```

is equivalent to:

```
def updateState(event: Event) = { state = state.update(event) }
```

So, `updateState` is a function of `Event => Unit`, which is exactly what method `persist` expects as its second parameter:

```
persist(AddUserEvent(userId))(updateState)
```

Below is the signature of method `persist` in [Akka PersistentActor](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-persistence/src/main/scala/akka/persistence/PersistentActor.scala):

```
trait PersistentActor extends Eventsourced with PersistenceIdentity {
  // ...
  def persist[A](event: A)(handler: A => Unit): Unit = {
    internalPersist(event)(handler)
  }
  // ...
}
```

It expects a `EventType => Unit` handler code block as its second parameter to handle specific persistence business logic that generally involves updating internal states of the actor.

Answer (score 1):

> Why can't we just use `def updateState(event:Event) = state.update(event)`?

The reason for the reassignment to the `state` variable is that `update` creates a new object. In other words, calling `state.update` doesn't mutate `state`; it makes a copy of `state` with the updated information.

This is the case with the example that you referenced:

```
var state = ExampleState()

def updateState(event: Evt): Unit =
  state = state.updated(event)
```

Looking at the code for [`ExampleState`](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/v2.5.19/akka-docs/src/test/scala/docs/persistence/PersistentActorExample.scala#L15), we see that the `updated` method actually creates a new `ExampleState` object:

```
def updated(evt: Evt): ExampleState = copy(evt.data :: events)
```